# Android List Item animate once on load

Tags: android, listview, animation

I have a listview that has each item animated into view. I basically created an animation similiar to the Material Design animation from [here](http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/components-progressandactivity-progressandactivity-2-drive.mobile-load.folders_large_xhdpi.webm). The animation is as follows:

```
<translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="50%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="750" />
<alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="600"/>
```

This is coupled with a offset to have each row item fade in slightly later than the previous one (done in adapter getView):

```
 Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.listitem_up);
 animation.setStartOffset(offset);
 row.startAnimation(animation);
 offset += 100;
```

Now initially when the list is created, everything is animated and its fine. But, any subsequent items that are revealed from scrolling have an increasingly long offset because it never resets. I can't figure out how to either a) reset the offset before a scroll, or b) only have the animation occur once on initial load.

I looked into the scroll listener, but from my own testing it seems to be triggered even on the initial load without a scroll, so I don't know enough about it to come up with a solution.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about reseting offset to 0 before  you call the "load animation" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have this code in the `getView` right?

Try :

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.listitem_up);
 animation.setStartOffset(position * 100);
 row.startAnimation(animation);
```

With this, the offset will always be `position * 100`, which might be helpful when the `getView` try to recycle/reuse the row.

EDIT :

I found this, you may want to take a look : [animate listView childs only once they appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193527/animate-listview-childs-only-once-they-appear)

Basically, he did the same thing like my answer, with more validation.

Comment: Yes this is done in the getView. I took a look at that other stackoverflow post, and its as close as I got to what I want. Although, there is still a slightly longer delay than what I would like. Ill keep the question open, if no one else can provide some insight then I will give you the checkmark. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SikhWarrior dont worry about the checkmark (uptove will be great, though :)). What do you mean by "slightly longer delay"?

Comment: Once you scroll one item and let go, there is a delay before it is animated, whereas what I want is that after you scroll, the next row to be animated should have 0 offset. Let me know if I explained that clearly, I'm typing on a phone and about to head to bed.

Comment: "next row to be animated should have 0 offset" Have you tried to do something like my comment? (reseting offset to 0 before you call the "load animation" ?). I havent tried that one in my code, cant really tell you the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. Where exactly would I reset the offset?

Comment: What will happen if we try this :animation.setStartOffset(100); ? The offset will always be 100. I never tried this, i used the answer i posted

Comment: The goal of the animation is to replicate that Material Design animation I linked, where each item fades in a little bit after the previous. If I set the offset to 100, then they would all come in at the same time.